# C++ Calculate the biggest, smallest and average number in different functions and print it. Program will fail to do the arithetics properly

Tags: c++

**The program will sometimes work properly if i only put the numbers in ascending order. 
It will fail tho if i try to randomly put numbers. The average number will fail to print properly like the arithmetics didnt work at all** 
I would appreciate any help.

**Full question here** : 
Define a class named Student with three private data for
registration number, name and grades in 8 courses (table). 
Also write the following member functions: 
A function for assigning values to private class data

• A function for displaying the data

• A function for the return of the maximum score

• A function for the return of the minimum score

• A function for the return of the average score

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    struct Student
    {
    
    private:
        string name;
        string lname;
        string mtr;
        int grades[8];
        int sum;
        int dbv = 0;
        int mo;
        int min;
        int max;
        int i, n, p;
    
    public:
        void insert()
        {
            int i;
            cout << "\nName : ";
            cin >> name;
            cout << "\nLast name: ";
            cin >> lname;
            cout << "\nID : ";
            cin >> mtr;
            for (i = 1; i < 9; i++)
            {
                cout << i << ") Give number : ";
                cin >> grades[i];
                sum += grades[i];
            }
        }
        int average()
        {
            mo = sum / 8;
        }
    
        int minimum()
        {
            min = grades[0];
            for (i = 1; i < 9; i++)
            {
                if (min > grades[i])
                {
                    min = grades[i];
                }
            }
        }
    
        int maximum()
        {
            max = grades[0];
            for (i = 1; i < 9; i++)
            {
                if (max < grades[i])
                {
                    max = grades[i];
                }
            }
        }
        int print()
        {
            cout << "\nPRINT : \n Name : " << name << "\n Last Name: " << lname << " \nID : " << mtr << "\nAverage : " << mo << "\nMax : " << max << "\nMin : " << min;
        }
    };
    
    int main()
    {
        Student std1;
        std1.insert();
        std1.average();
        std1.minimum();
        std1.maximum();
        std1.print();
    }
```

Comment: This is the perfect time to hone your debugging skills.  Sounds like you already have found a case where behavior is incorrect.  So, now it's time to prune that back to the most minimal case you can.  Then you have something to investigate by using your debugger and/or printing out the state of your variables to compare reality against expectation.

Comment: Oh...  by the way, the most introductory reading material on arrays in C++ (or C for that matter) will tell you that they are indexed starting from zero.  You are using them wrong.

Comment: The question is unclear and you have not provided example input and output demonstrating your problem. Also, it is very helpful to do things a little at a time and put some debugging cout statements to reassure yourself that what you think is being stored is what is actually being stored. Or, use a debugger and step through line by line.

Answer (score 1):

In `insert`, you didn't give a value to `grades[0]`. So in `minimum` and `maximum`, you're comparing grades with a memory garbage.

And, the length of the array is 8, so the index has to be in the range from 0 to 7.
But you're trying to access the 8th element. It means you will get memory garbage again or other variables.

Comment: ok i added [i] as a value, but now the program will not find the average number

Comment: @Reepz42 whats your code after edited?